# Is it possible to stop certain fields in a document from being included in replication in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Scenario: perhaps certain fields are sensitive and should not be sent over i.e. account related information - can once exclude them or do they need to be stored in a separate document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You can do filtered replication, so that only certain documents are replicated, and this is a very common mechanism used for ensuring that a replication to a user/client only includes the documents you want it to include, but filtered replication is just a boolean for the whole document.

Sensitive fields and replication is one of the reasons for splitting a document into multiple documents, so that you can filter out the documents you don't want to replicate.